# Add operation on same valued record in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I am trying to run query that sum of the same record that on the database. It is more clear to use codes instead of words.

```
class Track(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    isrc = models.CharField()
    ...

class Playlog(models.Model):
    track = models.ForeignKey(Track, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ....
```

On database there is multiple record which has same `isrc` value. To get real playlog data I needed to get total playlog count which has same isrc of all Track. I tried following query but it shows me a duplicated values of `Track`. if there is same `isrc` I wanted to get sum of all playlog of same `isrc` record.

```
Playlog.objects.values("track__isrc").annotate(Count("track__playlog", filter=Q(track__playlog__duration__gte=10))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add a `.order_by('track__isrc')` to force it to "fold". You should also count on the model, not on a related model:

```
Playlog.objects.values('track__isrc').annotate(
    Count('pk', filter=Q(duration__gte=10)
).orer_by('track__isrc')
```

That being said, if the same value of `isrc` means it is the same product, etc. It is better to make a model and a `ForeignKey` to that product, for example:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    isrc = mode.sCharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    # …

class Track(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    isrc = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # …

class Playlog(models.Model):
    track = models.ForeignKey(Track, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    duration = models.IntegerField()
    # …
```

Then you can annotate the `Product`, for example:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

Product.objects.annotate(
    total_play=Count('track__playlog', filter=Q(track__playlog__duration__gte=10))
)
```